# UITableView selectable list

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, selection

I am trying to implement a selectable list view. The list view contains some names. You can select or deselect multiple names. If a name is selected the cell style is changed to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.

But now I have a problem. Before you can deselect a name you have to press multiple times onto the cell. This is because `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` gets always called first.

```
// cellForRowAtIndexPath function
    if ([assignedPlayers containsObject:player.persistentData])
    {
        [cell setSelected:true];
        [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", player.persistentData.name];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:FALSE];
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

    [self.eventController removePlayerFromEvent:_editingEvent :[self.playerController getPlayerAtPosition:indexPath.row]];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:TRUE];
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    [self.eventController addPlayerToEvent:_editingEvent :[self.playerController getPlayerAtPosition:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Now I don't know how to fix this.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Your opening paragraph states that a single name can be selected. That conflicts with your update at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the example below where `_selectedList` contains the selected players and `_datasoureArray` is the datasource that contains all the players names.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL"];
  if(cell == nil)
   {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
   }
   cell.textLabel.text = [_datasoureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   if([_selectedList containsObject:[_datasoureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) //hear selected list is an mutable array wich holds only selected player
    {
      cell.selected = YES;
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
      cell.selected = NO;
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   if(cell)
   {
      if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
      {
        [_selectedList addObject:[_datasoureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];//add
      }
      else
      {
        if([_selectedList containsObject:[_datasoureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
       {
           [_selectedList removeObject:[_datasoureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; //remove
       }
     }
 }
 [tableView reloadData];
 NSLog(@"%@",_selectedList.description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the tableView to support multiple selection. Try the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.myTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

Then you won't need these two lines in the respective delegates:

```
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:TRUE];

[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:FALSE];
```

Comment: But the OP states they only want single selection.

Comment: Oh.. Sorry. When I saw the checkmark, I thought he needed multiple selection. I usually do that for multiple selection. Will delete answer now. Your answer is fit for his purpose. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a check for each selected indexes for e.g.: use an as Selected Indexes

No every time you select a cell add it to this array such as:

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if ([selectedIndex containsObject:indexPath]) {

            [selectedIndexes removeObject:indexPath];

        }else{

            [selectedIndexes addObject:indexPath];
       }

       [tableView reloadData];
    }
```

and then in CellForROwAtIndex

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
            if ([selectedIndex containsObject:indexPath]) {
 [cell setSelected:TRUE];
    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    [self.eventController addPlayerToEvent:_editingEvent :[self.playerController getPlayerAtPosition:indexPath.row]];
}

}else{
 [cell setSelected:FALSE];
    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

    [self.eventController removePlayerFromEvent:_editingEvent :[self.playerController getPlayerAtPosition:indexPath.row]];


}


}
```

this would be more effective rather then fetching the Cell from DidSelect Method just make sure to use [tableView reloadData]; in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Why are you doing this in the `didDeselectRow` method? It should be in the `didSelectRow` method. And it seems the OP only wants single selection.

Comment: so the cells don't have their own selected state? I thought the function `[cell setSelected:true];` should do that?

Comment: @HotPizzaBox May be ..I am not sure about that, this logic works for me though..I have used it may a times in my apps to accomplish something similar to what you are doing

Comment: I think this method is pretty weird for deselecting a raw. You have the `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` for performing any operations on deselecting a cell. This code should not be used IMO.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT well do you have any better idea. I agree with you but since my code does not work...

Comment: See my answer. You just need to set the multipleSelection enabled.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the accessoryType to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone when not containsObject.
Because the cell could be reused.
And you don't need to set selected when select or disselect.

```
if ([assignedPlayers containsObject:player.persistentData]){
    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
} else {
    cell.accessoryType= UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement functionality in following way, 
When you select a row you will check your array for person corresponding to that row if it already persent that remove it from array else add it to the array and reload your table. And in cellForRowAtIndexPath method check array if person exist set selected true else set selected false.

// cellForRowAtIndexPath function

```
{
    if ([assignedPlayers containsObject:player.persistentData])
    {
    [cell setSelected:true];
    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
    else 
    {
    [cell setSelected:Flase];
    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmarkNone];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", player.persistentData.name];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([assignedPlayers containsObject:player.persistentData])
    {
    [assignedPlayers removeObject:player.persistentData];
    }
    else
    {
    [assignedPlayers addObject:player.persistentData];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```